# Javascript and CSS animation render blocking

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

My web page has a sticky header with an image in it:

```
/* Simplified CSS: */
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    transition: height .5s;
}

header > img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

When the user scrolls down, the header smoothly becomes less high:

```
header.floating {
    height: 100px;
}
```

This scales the image due to it's 100% height. During the transition, the image becomes pixelated; anti-alias is removed to increase the browser's performance, I suppose.

My web page also has a welcome screen with different images in it. The image shown changes every 5 seconds. There is a progress bar to show the timer's progress.

```
/* Simplified CSS: */
section#welcome {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

section#welcome div#progress {
    width: 0.1%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

---

```
/* Simplified JavaScript & jQuery: */
setInterval(function() {
    changeImage();
    $("div#progress").animate({
        width: '100%'
    }, 5000);
}, 5000);
```

However; when the transition is *done*, the image remains pixelated -- it's anti alias seems to be blocked by jQuery's animate(). When I disable the jQuery, the image is rerendered after about a second.

---

**Things I've tried**

I tried adding an extra gap between the timers, to allow for the browser to rerender the images. This did not work.

I tried replacing the jQuery by a CSS animation. This did not work either.

Where to go from here? How can I maintain the progress bar, but allow for the browser (or force it) to rerender the image in the header?

Comment: You could try to "re-set" the src attribute (first set it to "", then back to what you had before). Otherwise you could remove the img tag and append a new one.

Comment: I've had similar problems in other use cases. Things that have worked for me (although none work universally) include resetting the src attribute, as @Dodekeract suggests; adjusting the z-index; slightly changing the width and then re-setting the width...basically anything to tell the browser's rendering engine to repaint that screen area. You'll have to test across browsers though, since these things vary quite a bit across platforms.